# Android VideoView with ImageView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to click on an image and set the visibility of VideoView and make the imageView invisible.However when I click on image a white nbackground appears.Please help.

```
feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    String substr2 =item.getImge().substring(item.getImge().length() - 3);
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(item.getImge()!=null)
        {
            if(substr2.equals("jpg"))
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"Its image");
            }
            else if(substr2.equals("mp4"))
            {
                feedImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                MediaController mc=new MediaController(getActivity());
                mc.setAnchorView(vid);
                mc.setMediaPlayer(vid);
                Log.e(TAG,"In mp4 "+item.getImge());
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getImge());
                vid.setMediaController(mc);
                vid.setVideoURI(uri);
                vid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vid.start();

                Log.e(TAG, "Its video");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Layout of the imageView and videoView

```
<com.example.adapter.FeedImageView
    android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Complete layout file -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textColor="#0f84cc"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

       <!--  <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:background="#000000"
             /> -->

            <com.example.adapter.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/downloadbtn" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Download"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#0f84cc"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Anything unusual in the logcat? Are yu 100% sure that URI that you are using is correct?

Comment: @KirillK used Logcat to get the uri and its of mp4 format - URI is https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/12708125_217442355268913_651092529_n.mp4

Comment: Ok, then please post the complete layout file

Comment: @KirillK I've put the complete layout file.Please suggest any changes if required.

Comment: After initial layout initial height of the video is 0 and stays like that. If I understand correctly you'd like to replace your image with the video? See my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have image and video stacked one on top of another you should put them in a container like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.example.adapter.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
             />
</FrameLayout>
```

Note that video's height is  `match_parent` to make it same size as initial image

Comment: I've followed your solution but the VideoView just doesnt become visible after the ImageView collapses.

Comment: Do you hear video sound playing? Did you ask for the internet permission in the manifest, so that video can be downloaded?

Comment: I have all the necessary permissions, I'm actually making a instagram like project and I get the pictures from feed but cannot put the video in the already defined view for images so want to get the videoView when click on imageview.Also I hear no sound when I click.

Comment: Try setting various listeners on `VideoView`, like [`setOnErrorListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29) this may help you to debug/figure out what happens

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using invisible use gone:

Replace:

```
feedImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

with:

```
feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Using your approach, The ImageView collapses but VideoView does not appear.